# Ctrl-W at :terminal (default terminal behavior expected)

Tags: key-bindings, terminal

I am very fond of Vim's `:terminal`, though whenever I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> (expecting to erase the last typed word at prompt), Vim captures the key press and enters pane navigation mode. So I end up having to <kbd>esc</kbd> and then perform multiple backspaces. This wastes precious milliseconds of life.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Backspace</kbd> (default behavior in many GUIs) and also nothing. What could be a workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to move the cursor out of the terminal](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/23217/how-to-move-the-cursor-out-of-the-terminal)

Comment: Absolutely not. It is easy to `Ctrl-W` and get out of terminal. I want the opposite. I want to _stay at the terminal and to have the last word erased_ as this would happen in any other terminal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To send the original keystroke, you can use `<C-w>.` (note the period).

That said, I too find it annoying to have to remember.

Useful reference: https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-typing

Answer (score 12):

You can set [`'termwinkey'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27termwinkey%27) to a sequence other than `<C-W>` to use a different keystroke to access the special sequences on the terminal.

For example:

```
set termwinkey=<C-X>
```

Or:

```
set termwinkey=<F1>
```

See also [`:help terminal-typing`](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html#terminal-typing).